# Cardano Balance While Staking

Tags: wallet

I am currently staking Cardano in Daedalus 4.6.0. When I started staking, my balance shows up as ***. Can someone please explain why? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must have the "discreet" feature turned on - it is the little eyeball towards the top right of Daedalus, just to the left of the notification bell.

To view your balance, simply click the crossed out eyeball, it will uncross and you'll see your balance.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked!